# MySql remote database manipulation in Android

Tags: android, mysql

How can access mysql remotely without using PHP or JSON...or any other method?

Comment: What do you mean?. You can connect remote mysql like you connect local one. Over TCP provided port is opened.

Comment: what do you mean by "you want to connect remotely without using any other method" ?? :D

Comment: Unfortunately programming usually requires SOME TYPE of method. Not using PHP, JSON or ANY OTHER METHOD isn't gonna cut it ;-)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
    package com.example.login2;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class login2 extends Activity {
    EditText un,pw;
    TextView error;
    Button ok;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    un=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_un);
    pw=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_pw);
    ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    error=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_error);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override

    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", un.getText().toString()));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pw.getText().toString()));

    //String valid = "1";
    String response = null;
    try {
    response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://engiguide.com/check.php", postParameters);  //Enetr Your remote PHP,ASP, Servlet file link
    String res=response.toString();
    // res = res.trim();
    res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");
    //error.setText(res);
    if(res.equals("1"))
    error.setText("Correct Username or Password");
    else
    error.setText("Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password");

    } catch (Exception e) {

    un.setText(e.toString());
    }}
    });

}}
```

Check [this link](http://webdesignergeeks.com/mobile/android/android-login-authentication-with-remote-db/), it explains in detail how to access Remote DB like MySQL using PHP,ASP,JSP

Answer (score 1):

In programming just replace `localhost` with the ip of remote machine in mysql connection url.
and if you wanna access it using some tool like MySQL GUI then give ip of remote machine in that. or connect by following command:

```
mysql -u user -h remotehost remotedatabase
```

Read this for more: [Connect to mysql server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html).

---

**Based on your tag update:**

See this link: http://www.anddev.org/post91169.html#p91169 it shows how to connect to mysql in android. What you need is just replace the ip `127.0.0.1` with the ip of remote machine in the code.

Comment: can you please give me any tutorial or code link ?   will appreciate your help ...

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways including simply using the mysql client with like so:

```
mysql -u username -p -h remote_host_ip < script.sql
```

Comment: mysql client isn't available on Android (see tags of question), although he didn't mention it in his question explicitly.

Comment: @mathias He changed the question after I answered it to include android and added the tag afterward.

Comment: Oh I see, got it :) Yeah, saw he also posted a duplicate one already... voted for close (the other one).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use web service, php and/or json, or similar. Cannot use jdbc directly from Android.

(Please see the right sidebar of this question's page, this same has already been asked several times before.)