# Server requirement

Tags: android, database, webserver

We are interested in purchasing a server for storing a MySQL database that is used by an Android application. Just to understand, does the server only need to support MySQL, or are other requirements for a server for mobile use?

Comment: This depends entirely on what your application is and what the server-client and any server-server relations are.

Comment: The android application just create, update, delete data from mysql database

Comment: What is your current solution and why is it deficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the database "directly" (like it was local), this could help: [MySql remote database manipulation in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672548/mysql-remote-database-manipulation-in-android)

But you might need some additional server functionality, at least in the future. Then you could use a server which also offers PHP. PHP + MySQL are usually offered together, it's very common/popular and it's cheap. Since you don't seem to have any special requirements for the server functionality, PHP is probably suitable.

Answer (score 2):

Your Android application would probably not work directly with a remote MySQL database.

In general, you would use write a web service API to act as middleware, communicating with your Android application and the database. Your Android application would make HTTP requests to the web service, which would in turn perform CRUD on your database. In this case, your server would need both a web server (with support for Java or PHP or whatever language you choose to use for the web service) and a database server. See [How to have Android app work with MySQL online database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116456/how-to-have-android-app-work-with-mysql-online-database)